# Is there way to receive a trigger when our Magento extension is installed?

Tags: magento

We would like to know if our extension was installed on Magento server or at least was downloaded from Magento Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento install scripts are just normal PHP code. You could easily add a call to [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) or [`file_get_contents(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to your own servers.

Magento even [wraps curl in its own interface](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Http/Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl.html), so this is quite feasible.

I would argue that making a request to your own servers for no real technical reason is rather impolite, so I'd suggest also adding an option in your config, much in the same way that other applications give an option to send anonymous usage statistics when they are installed.

Comment: great answer! the only problem is - at the moment customers see the config, the install scrip was already triggered :) so actually no real polite option here...

Comment: yeah, I did think of that. That said, there are plenty of "impolite" Magento modules out there, and merely phoning home at install time would indeed rank on the more-polite end of the spectrum.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that solution. Hoped there will be some built in hook in magento server or magento connect which is triggered when the extension is installed. That would also solve the registration flow. (Shopify for example have it)

Comment: @WillPalmer: Sorry for a newbie question but Do i have to use .._Model_Resource_Setup kind of install script? My functionality has nothing to do with Model change, seems kind of abuse but I didn't find any other examples. Tnx again